# PyMC3 large MvNormal prior

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I want to specify large multivariate normal distribution as a prior in PyMC3. The precision matrix of this distribution has determinant numerically equal to zero. It seems this is a problem for PyMC3. Any suggestions? I only need to maximize the posterior, which can be done regardless of the value of the determinant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pymc3 gets the determinant by computing the cholesky decomposition. It also does this on a log-scale, so this really shouldn't underflow. It is possible that the matrix is ill conditioned and the cholesky decomposition fails however. In this case you could add a small diagonal to your matrix.

If you are sure that you want to work with an ill conditioned matrix, you could write your own version of `pm.MvNormal`, that doesn't include the det. Something along the lines of this:

```
class MvNormalNoDet(pm.Continuous):
    def __init__(self, mu, tau, *args, **kwargs):
        self._mu = tt.as_tensor_variable(mu)
        self._tau = tt.as_tensor_variable(tau)
        self.mean = self.median = self.mode = self._mu
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def logp(self, value):
        diff = value - self._mu
        return -0.5 * (diff * tt.dot(self._tau, diff)).sum(axis=-1)
```